# Import Kotlin file to build.gradle.kts

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In my Android project I am trying to figure out how to import a Kotlin file from a build-logic module to my app.

The application module is called mobile, resides in an app folder (→ app:mobile) and declares the namespace `com.my.application` (this is for demonstration purpose and not the actual name).

A build-logic module is included in my settings.gradle.kts like this:

```
pluginManagement {
    includeBuild("build-logic")
}
```

Within the build-logic module I created a path to the file I want to import matching the namespace `com.my.application`. The absolute path is:
`project-root/build-logic/convention/src/main/kotlin/com/my/application/ApplicationVersions.kt`. The file ApplicationVersions contains this singleton:

```
object ApplicationVersions {  
    const val MIN = 21  
    const val COMPILE = 34
    const val TARGET = 34
}
```

I would expect that I can import ApplicationVersions with the `import com.mobile.app.ApplicationVersions` statement in my app's build.gradle.kts file. However the import can not be found.

Is there something that I am missing?